# Multiple db connections in sails.js with migration setting per connection

Tags: node.js, migration, sails.js, waterline

I'm using two connections in sails app: mongodb and postgresql. For mongodb i want to use "alter" strategy, but postgres db must be readonly. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define it at the connection level, but [you can override the configuration for the models of your choice](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings).

```
// in api/models/PosgresModel.js
module.exports = {
  migrate: 'safe',
  attributes: {
    // The attributes definitions
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what i need